# Test the domain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one set of code deployed on 2 separate Heroku apps, so one runs at:

```
www.myapp.co
```

and the other runs at

```
myapp-testing.heroku.com
```

Because one is a testing app and the other is production, there are a couple of places where I want to distinguish between the two. Is it possible for Rails to detect which one is which, given that the only difference I know of is the web domain?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am following you. You want to know the host name in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.headers['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `RAILS_ENV` environment variable correctly for each instance (e.g. `production` for one, `test` for the other) using e.g.:

```sh
$ heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=test RACK_ENV=test
```

...then you can use `Rails.env` to find out which environment you're running in, e.g.:

```
if Rails.env == 'test'
  # ...
end

# OR:

if Rails.env.test?
  # ...
end
```

This is pretty much the standard way of dealing with separate environments like you describe.